# Pull multiple key values from Json Python

Tags: python, json, pandas, key

I am trying to write code for a project that pulls multiple pieces of data from a JSON API. I've got the code written where it will narrow it down to the segment I want and pull a full list of a given key (siteSlatePlayerId). However, I am trying to get it to also pull 'name' at the same time.

Example: 100031, Lebron James

How can I change this loop (or if you recommend another way) to pull 'siteSlatePlayerId' and 'name' at the same time? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
df = pd.read_json('https://resultsdb-api.rotogrinders.com/api/slates?start=11/03/2019')
df2 = df
df3 = df2[(df2['slateTypeName'] == 'Classic') & (df2['sport'] == 3)]
#df3.to_csv("output3.csv")

Player_Slate = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(df3["slatePlayers"])
print(Player_Slate)

###########################################################
# Get Unique ID for player
###########################################################
def get_playerid(data, key):
   for key in data:
       try:
           if (key == 'siteSlatePlayerId'):
               return (data[key])
       except:
           print('error')
   return 0

for siteSlatePlayerId in Player_Slate.slatePlayers:
   playerid = [get_playerid(x, "siteSlatePlayerId") for x in siteSlatePlayerId]
print(playerid)
```

This gives me all the player IDs:
['13689965', '13689969', '13689973', '13689977', '13689982', '13689986', '13689989', '13689993', '13689997', '13690002', '13690005', '13690007', '13690011', '13690013', '13690018', '13690022', '13690026', '13690028', '13690030', '13690034', '13690037', '13690041', '13690045', '13690050', '13690054', '13690059', '13690062', '13690066', '13690070', '13690074', '13690078', '13690081', '13690084', '13690088', '13690092', '13690096', ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, obtain a clean df:

```
players_df = pd.json_normalize(df3['slatePlayers'].apply(lambda x: x[0]))
```

Or `players_df = pd.json_normalize(df['slatePlayers'].str[0])` if you prefer. [pandas.json_normalize](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html) normalize semi-structured JSON data into a flat table.

Then, you can get what you want:

```
>>> players_df[['name','siteSlatePlayerId']]
    name    siteSlatePlayerId
0   Kawhi Leonard   13691028
1   Lamar Jackson   13676980
2   Lamar Jackson   13680443
3   Ezekiel Elliott 13679976
4   Ezekiel Elliott 13680092
```

---

Full code:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_json('https://resultsdb-api.rotogrinders.com/api/slates?start=11/03/2019')
df2 = df
df3 = df2[(df2['slateTypeName'] == 'Classic') & (df2['sport'] == 3)]
df3.to_csv("output3.csv")
players_df = pd.json_normalize(df['slatePlayers'].apply(lambda x: x[0]))
players_df[['name','siteSlatePlayerId']]
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the response. When I try to reference Player_Slate like that, I just get a ton of errors:Traceback (most recent call last). LIke this one:
  File "C:\Users\A\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1640, in _validate_read_indexer
    raise KeyError(f"None of [{key}] are in the [{axis_name}]")
KeyError: "None of [Index(['siteSlatePlayerId', 'name'], dtype='object')] are in the [columns]"

Comment: That is exactly what I want. And thanks for the time to help! However, when I copy that exact code like you have it, I still get a bunch of errors for some reason.Here is my code that gets the errors  df = pd.read_json('https://resultsdb-api.rotogrinders.com/api/slates?start=11/03/2019')
df2 = df
df3 = df2[(df2['slateTypeName'] == 'Classic') & (df2['sport'] == 3)]
#df3.to_csv("output3.csv")

Player_Slate = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(df3["slatePlayers"])
print(Player_Slate)

players_df = pd.json_normalize(df['slatePlayers'].apply(lambda x: x[0]))
players_df[['name','siteSlatePlayerId']]

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Yes...I think this may lead me to what I need. If I switch the df to df3 in your second-to-last line...I get the players I want. I may still need a for loop though to get them all, right? It only returns the first instance of each row.